# Why does this array not print?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

**My Code:**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

function printArray(arr){
  arrAtr = "";
  for(count = 0; count < arr; count++){
    arrAtr += (String(arr[count]) + " ")
  }
  document.write(arrAtr);
}

printArray(arr)
```

This does not print the array.I am expecting :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: `myArr` or `arr`? Also `arr.length` in the for conditional.

Comment: Sorry it was `arr` only but problem was with arr.length Sorry !! @noahnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are errors in your code.

You have to replace

```
printArray(myArr)
```

with

```
printArray(arr);
```

AND replace

```
for(count = 0; count < arr; count++){
```

with

```
for(count = 0; count < arr.length; count++){
```

Comment: Hey I know that, StackOverflow asked me to wait for 4 minutes to accept the answer ! I am not a BAD guy okay ....

Comment: @TilakMadichetti Nether though that of you ;) Just thought you might forget you know. Nice dev

Comment: By the way, I like your selfie !!